# Как деплоить телеграм бота с sqlite3?

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3, heroku, deploy

Я делаю телеграм бота с БД. И пользуюсь sqlite3 т.к. оно понятнее для меня. Но вот вопрос: как можно деплоить бота на хероку с sqlite3? Помогите плиз